# how do i change the format of a string representing time in android?

Tags: android

I have a string which i retrieve from the database which is of the following format

30-08-2010 12:30:00

i need to convert that string into the following format

Aug 30 2010 12:30 PM

How do i do this?
Also tell me how to convert the string into a date object.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look around `java.util.*` for more info. It has nothing to do with Android.

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date date = (Date)formatter1.parse("30-08-2010 12:30:00");   

DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a");
String newFormattedString = formatter2.format(date);
```